# HTML5 Flexbox line break

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I want three centered `div`s, broken onto separate lines. However, this code doesn't break lines (like `display: block`).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

What I wanted:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lika in a column you mean:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

or perhaps

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```